# How to move the whole SVG to right or left?

Tags: html, svg

I have a svg element but i cannot use any css to move it right or left.

```
var w = 500;
var h = 600;

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .style("background-color","#c9e8fd")

var g = svg.append("g");
```

Right now the svg with the blue backgorund is stuck on the left side of the screen just want to move it to the right and a little down. Any ideas?

Comment: why no CSS, given that's the way you actually do this.

Comment: Ok thank you, i was using the left and right oprions in CSS but they do not work on SVG elements. I just used trasform and translate and that done the trick. @RobertLongson